# Can I parse a SLIM file with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have a Rails application that I am trying to implement a WYSIWYG editor (mercury) so a user can update the static pages of the site.

The user would be a power user, or some sort of person I want updating my site. The page would be something like the index.slim.html page. The content to update is static content (not stored in the DB).

I am using [Mercury](http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/).

The content to update would be something like this:

```
      hr
        #header_content data-mercury='full'
          p.lead Ratione, quasi, enim voluptates porro voluptas quaerat recusandae reprehenderit vitae aliquid earum ex quo assumenda doloremque ea dolores maxime error suscipit exercitationem.
```

I have the following data being submitted to a Rails controller:

```
{"content"=>{"header_content"=>{"type"=>"full", "data"=>{}, "value"=>"<p class=\"lead\">\n                  Ratione, quasi, enim voluptates porro voluptas quaerat recusandae reprehenderit vitae aliquid earum ex quo assumenda doloremque ea dolores maxime error suscipit exercitationem.\n                </p>", "snippets"=>{}}}, "_method"=>"PUT", "controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"mercury_update", "id"=>"index", "page"=>{"content"=>{"header_content"=>{"type"=>"full", "data"=>{}, "value"=>"<p class=\"lead\">\n                  Ratione, quasi, enim voluptates porro voluptas quaerat recusandae reprehenderit vitae aliquid earum ex quo assumenda doloremque ea dolores maxime error suscipit exercitationem.\n                </p>", "snippets"=>{}}}}}
```

Or printed a bit prettier:

```
page to update:
  "index" 
path to this page:
  app/views/pages/index.html.slim

Content:
  Html ID:
    header_content
  html:
    <p class="lead">
                  Ratione, quasi, enim voluptates porro voluptas quaerat recusandae reprehenderit vitae aliquid earum ex quo assumenda doloremque ea dolores maxime error suscipit exercitationem.
                </p>
```

So, the `<div>` with the ID  of `header_content` needs to have its content replaced with the HTML there.

How can I get Nokogiri to find that ID, update the content (in Slim) and save it? Do I need to just NOT use Slim for any pages that need to have this feature?

Comment: I am afraid your question is not really clear, what do you mean by "update the content (in slim) and save it"? Don't you want instead to save your HTML textarea in your database and output it on your static page?

Comment: Would that be static? I've never done this before, but my thought was I wanted the user to update the HTML (not an entry in the DB). Is that a bad idea?

Comment: So in other words the user will edit your page on the fly without saving it in a persistent storage?

Comment: So what you call "static file" is an actual file on your filesystem and not the "static pages" your were mentioning in the OP? I'm sorry but this is really a bit confusing...

Comment: Updated for clarity.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to add `<edit/>` tags in your document, and, in general, is not recommended. We're basically creating Wikipedia-type reference articles here. We can see what you've changed if necessary, and having a question that flows and reads naturally is more important. You can use a simple `---` markup that adds a horizontal-rule to the page if you feel it's essential to call out new information, otherwise put the information into the question where it belongs and we'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best solution, but it does what I need:

```
def get_match(text, key)
  return_hash = {}
  replace_lines = []
  line_num = 0  
  indent = -1
  matched_line = -1
  last_line = text.count-1
  text.each do |line| 
    line_num += 1
    if line.include? key
      indent = line.index(/[^ ]/)
      return_hash[:matched_line] = {:line_number => line_num, :line_text => line, :leading_spaces => indent}
      after_match = text[line_num..-1]
      i = indent
      after_line_num = line_num
      after_match.each do |l|
        after_line_num +=1
        i = l.index(/[^ ]/)
        if i <= indent
            break
        else
            replace_lines.append({:line_number=> after_line_num, :line_text => l, :leading_spaces => i})
        end

      end 
      return_hash[:replace_lines] = replace_lines
      break
    end
   end
   return_hash
 end


def new_slim_page_content (old_page_content, new_content, key)
    #run first function here
    matches = get_match(old_page_content, key)

    #create two temp files... convert html 2 slim
    input_file = Tempfile.new('input')
    input_file.write(new_content)
    input_file.close
    output_file = Tempfile.new('output')
    output_file.close

    # Can I do this without using system call?
    `html2slim "#{input_file.path}" "#{output_file.path}"`

    #put output_file contents in variable and delete temp files
    output_file.open
    output = output_file.read
    input_file.unlink
    output_file.unlink

    #delete old lines
    matched_line = matches[:matched_line][:line_number] - 1 #returns line number, want index
    replace_lines = matches[:replace_lines]
    replace_lines.each do |line|
        old_page_content.delete_at(matched_line + 1) #the next index
    end

    #create new lines
    output = output.split("\n")
    initial_offset = (" " * (matches[:matched_line][:leading_spaces] +2)) 
    output.map! { |line| initial_offset + line + "\n"}
    old_page_content.insert(matched_line + 1, output).flatten!
    old_page_content = old_page_content.join
end


text = []
path_to_page = 'C:/dev/best_in_show/app/views/pages/index.html.slim'

File.open(path_to_page, 'r') do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
        text.append(line)
    end
end

new_text =  "<p class=\"lead\">test</p>"
key = "#header_content"
new_page = new_slim_page_content(text, new_text, key)
 File.open(path_to_page, 'w') do |f|
    f.write(new_page)
 end
```